# Labels strangely rendered in PDF

Tags: plotting, export, pdf-format, labeling

I'm new to Mathematica so I apologize if this is obvious to answer. Anyway, using the following code (most of it is extraneous, to make the plot look the way I want) I plotted the Morse potential,

```
V[r_] := Exp[-2 (r - 1)] - 2 Exp[-(r - 1)]
p = Plot[V[r], {r, 0, 5}, Ticks -> {Range[0, 5, .5], Range[-1, 1, .25]}, 
  TicksStyle -> Directive[FontOpacity -> 0, FontSize -> 0], 
  AxesLabel -> {HoldForm[r], HoldForm[V[r]]}, 
  AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[0.035]]
```

which yields

[image]

Now when I export this as PDF, using

```
Export["PathToLocation\\morse-potential.pdf", p, "PDF"]
```

the $V(r)$ label gets scrambled a bit:

[image]

I've also tried what would happen if I left out the optional arguments: the ticks are rendered exactly the same way,

[image]

What's going on here and how can I avoid it? I'm on Win8 with Mathematica 10.0.1.0 and Adobe Reader 11.0.10.

Comment: what OS? versions?

Comment: I'm on Win8 with Mathematica 10.0.1.0 and Adobe Reader 11.0.10

Comment: did you `Export["fig.pdf",%]` or save as? If it is the latter, it is a known bug.

Comment: It has been a problem in many different ways. If you search for it, it has came up many times.

Comment: @chris I used `Export`, see my latest edit.

Comment: @ChenStatsYu Perhaps my googling skills leave something to be desired but I did search for it and unfortunately couldn't find this particular problem.

Comment: On macosX mathematica 10.0.2   it works.

Comment: @Wouter You can try out some of the work arounds people are suggesting. If do not work, you might have to use a different format. Mathematica does not work with PDF files very well in V10.

Comment: @ChenStatsYu Well I would, but I don't know any work arounds nor have I found any online I'm afraid. If you have a link to some of these suggestions, it would be appreciated.

Comment: @Wouter Top right corner, if you just seach "PDF", there are a lot posts. Some have the similar problems and might help.

Comment: @ChenStatsYu Thanks! However, all of the workarounds seem to involve using `Export`, which is what I did in the first place. The other suggestion I see is reverting back to MMA 10.0.1, which is the version I am already on. I'll keep looking though...

Comment: @Wouter Yes, that was my point. MMA does not seen to work well with PDF. You might try a different format, eg. JPEG if that is acceptable.

Comment: @ChenStatsYu Oh, well actually it isn't really acceptable. But I guess, at the moment, I have no other choice. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Wouter My suggestion is that, if you have ACROBAT, you can export the whole document, and then crop the image. That's what I did most of the time.

Comment: @ChenStatsYu Thanks for the tip, I actually went for an EPS-export which I then converted with pdflatex using epstopdf. That works as expected.

Comment: If you used `Export` then this is not the usual PDF export bug that people are talking about.  I am not able to reproduce this problem in either 10.0.2 or 10.1.0 on OS X Yosemite.  Also, I did use version 10.0.1 for exporting PDFs and making several figures, so I really doubt that 10.0.1 usually does this.   I suspect that this problem is unique to your computer, and if it is, the only explanation I can imagine is some sort of font problem ... whole this sounds stupid, have you tried restarting Mathematica or even restarting the computer?

Comment: Either way, why don't you upgrade to 10.0.2, or if your license allows, to 10.1.0, and see if the problem persists?  You should know that 10.0.2 does have a serious PDF export bug when using Save As... to export graphics.  `Export` works fine though.  10.1.0 works well with Save As... as well.

Comment: @Szabolcs I've checked on a different computer (same version of MMA and Win8 OS) and got the same result, which is weird because before today many other PDFs were generated without a problem on that machine. Restarting MMA didn't work, I didn't check if restarting the computer does, but I doubt it will considering the problem was reproducible on the second machine. I'm not sure about the license but will look into that.

Answer (score 2):

Try to avoid transparent `Ticks`, or FontSize -> 0, probably this is a problem for PDF. Instead you can define your Ticks directly without Labels, if you want to have them like that.

```
V[r_] := Exp[-2 (r - 1)] - 2 Exp[-(r - 1)]
p = Plot[V[r], {r, 0, 5}, 
Ticks -> { {#, ""} & /@ Range[0, 5, .5], {#, ""} & /@ 
 Range[-1, 1, .25]},

AxesLabel -> {"r", "V[r]"}, 
AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[0.035], ImageSize->500]

Export["morse-potential.pdf", p, "PDF", ImageSize -> 500]
```

Try also to set a fixed ImageSize at least in your Export.
I hope this helps, but i could not reproduce this problem on my system.

Hint: Its easier to give the AxesLabels as strings.

**EDIT:**

maybe this is easier to read and to modify:

```
Ticks -> {Table[{x,""},{x,0,5,.5}], Table[{y,""},{y,-1,1,.25}]}
```

**EDIT2:**

Have you tried changing the FontFamilie?

```
 SetOptions[Plot, BaseStyle -> {Large, FontFamily -> "Times", Italic}]
```

Comment: Well the problem persisted if I left out the optional arguments in the Plot command so I don't think the Transparent Ticks or 0 Fontsize are causing problems in this case.  Also, giving the labels as strings only made things worse: every symbol is then rendered as one of those "L" looking objects in my examples. This makes me suspect it's a problem with fonts... But thanks for the tip on the Ticks without Labels, that will be most useful :)

Comment: @Wouter year try to play around with FontFamilies. e.g. `SetOptions[Plot, 
 BaseStyle -> {Large, FontFamily -> "Times", Italic}]`

Comment: The `Times` FontFamily doesn't work either, but I'll keep trying a few others...

Comment: @Wouter i can only recommend you to contact WRI directly. Make a bugreport on this at:

-------service AT wolfram DOT com---------

I recently made a bugreport and got a very nice answer 3 days later. The seem to be happy if users help to improve Mathematica. You should tell them your Mathematica-Version and Operating Sytem, visible by `$Version`. You can also attach a notebook to make a clear example. good luck

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a real solution to the Export As PDF problem but it is a useful workaround in case other workarounds like reverting back to MMA 10.0.1 or using Export instead of Save As don't work for you (as was the case for me since I was already in MMA 10.0.1 and had used Export). You could of course always export as a raster graphics format like JPEG or PNG but you would have to sacrifice quality which I wasn't willing to do.

Instead, you can export as EPS and compile the following TeX-file:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx,epstopdf}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{myGraphics.eps}
\end{document}
```

This will generate a PDF with your graphics as well as all text (labels, legend) intact. Obviously if the idea is to incorporate the graphics into a TeX-generated PDF file anyway, you can just add the appropriate packages to your preamble and include it directly in your TeX-file.

The reason for the trouble, as I understand it, is that the PDF format will attempt to interpret symbols and work with fonts, while the EPS format will just take your graphics as they are.

Comment: Since you probably need a quick workaround for your project, you can also try [generating the labels using LaTeX](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/latex-typesetting-in-mathematica.html).  I still find it very strange that this happens on your computer and I doubt that this is a general problem that happens with *every* installation of 10.0.1 on Windows ...

Comment: Thanks for the link! For the project I need this for, I'm quite content to use the workaround in my answer here, since I only need the one figure and I'm not too concerned with font consistency in this case. But I'll definitely have a look at this MaTeX package for future projects!

Comment: would it not be easier to use `epstopdf` to convert eps to pdf than having to install Latex and compile a document just to do this conversion? There is also many free online sites that converts eps files to pdf. This is assuming the goal is just to convert eps to pdf.

Comment: @Nasser Yeah I guess you could just convert eps to pdf without LaTeX as well. :)